# Difference between 11_223 and 11223?

Tags: ruby

What is difference and why did someone write number with underscore?

```
irb(main):001:0> a = 11_223
=> 11223
irb(main):002:0> b = 11223
=> 11223
irb(main):003:0> a == b
=> true
irb(main):004:0> a === b
=> true
irb(main):005:0> 11_223 === 11223
=> true
```

Comment: Because it is much easier to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write 1 million in numbers, you would usually do:

1,000,000

and not:

1000000

To make it more readable.

You can do the same thing in Ruby with an underscore:

1_000_000

Ruby can't use the `,`, because that's already used in other things (like function arguments), so the "strange" underscore character is used.